# Python return if not statement explanation

Tags: python

I couldn't understand this example:

```
def mysum(L):
 first, *rest = L
 return first if not rest else first + mysum(rest)
```

I supposed that the statement means that first != rest, so it must returns first, but it returns first + mysum(rest).
Can you explain why?
TIA

Comment: `if not rest: return first else: first + mysum(rest)`?

If rest is not true it returns first else it recursively calls itself until it returns first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't understand the ternary, re-write it.

```
if not rest: 
    return first 
else:
    return first + mysum(rest)
```

In words, if there is nothing left, return what you have, otherwise return the current element plus the summation of the remaining list.

> I supposed that the statement means that first != rest,

Nope. `if not rest` is the statement, as in

```
>>> not []
True
```